# Android Live Wall Papers that change random pictures from drawable

Tags: android, image, random, drawable

Can someone give such a code or at least an idea how to make such wallpapers.
I guess I got to use Vieflipper but I cant use Random with this. Am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks a bit unspecific. In any case, to put it simple, let's assume you have an ImageView that you want to change dynamically in a random manner. The structure should look something like this:

```
imv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Resources rsrc= getResources();
imid = R.drawable.yourimagename;
Drawable drawable= rsrc.getDrawable(imid);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rsrc,drawable);
imv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

In this example, imid is hardcoded, but you could easily change it dinamically. For instance, create an array list of integers containing your desired images ids and then access them in a loop or whenever a condition is met (for instance every 30 seconds).

Eg:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listofimagesids = new ArrayList<Integer>;
listofimagesids.add(R.drawable.yourimagename1)
listofimagesids.add(R.drawable.yourimagename2)
...
listofimagesids.add(R.drawable.yourimagenameN)

Random rand = new Random();

if (youcondition){
  int n = rand.nextInt(listofimagesids.size());
  Drawable drawable= rsrc.getDrawable(n);
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rsrc,drawable);
  imv.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Of course this is just pseudo-code, but it might guide you a bit. Hope it helps.